# Maintaining Hyperlinks From Excel in PDF

Tags: python

I am currently using the ExportToFixedFormat function in Python to convert Excel spreadsheets to PDF format. However, the issue I'm having is that the hyperlinks I created in Excel no longer work in the PDF. Has anyone had this issue and know how to get around it? The hyperlinks are to cells within the same workbook. I realize it's not exactly a coding question but this is a key feature that I need to implement.

Comment: Did you check will several PDF viewers or just one? Have you tried to do it directly from Excel (instead of python) to see if the PDF then contains the links?

Comment: I've only checked the one we're using right now, I don't remember the version of Acrobat Reader I'm using at work. Are you suggesting to convert from Excel to PDF using a third party tool? The conversion needs to be automated, which is why we're using the Python function.

Comment: No I wasn't suggesting that. Just that if doing it manually from Excel shows same problem, then it is not a programming question so question should be removed and posted in appropriate forum. If manually from Excel the problem can be made to go away by, for instance, setting an option in the dialog that shows up when saving to PDF, then the programming question becomes how to configure this programmatically via win32com (I presume that is what you are using -- if so then add the win32com tag).